# Sublime text shell command output

Tags: ruby, rspec, sublimetext3

I'm having those lines overlaying my code every time a ruby test fails (using [TestRspec](https://github.com/astrauka/TestRSpec)):

[image]

How to make them not appear?
It's driving me nuts.

Thanks.

Comment: Turn the setting `show_errors_inline` off in your user preferences.

Comment: Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 2):

As @OdatNard suggested, you need to set `show_errors_inline` to false.

This feature has been introduced in Build 3124:

> Build errors are now shown inline at the location where they occurred. This is controlled with the show_errors_inline setting.

Check the changelog here: https://www.sublimetext.com/3, Build 3124.